# Scanner not working

Tags: java, string, terminal, java.util.scanner

I have this code:

```
byte[] nombre = new byte[20];
                System.out.print("Cuenta a modificar: ");
                cuenta = s.nextInt();
                boolean existe = estaRepetido(cuenta);
                if (existe == false){
                    System.out.println("La cuenta no existe");
                }
                else {
                    String nomCliente;
                    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
                    nomCliente = s.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Cantidad: ");
                    double cantidad = Double.parseDouble(s.nextLine());
                    for( int i = 0; i < 20 && i < nomCliente.getBytes().length; i++ ){
                        nombre[i] = nomCliente.getBytes()[i];
                    }
                    String nomModificar = new String (nombre);
                    modificar(cuenta, nomModificar, cantidad);
                }
```

but when run on the terminal somehow it overseas the nomCliente = s.nextLine(); ending with something like does this:

```
Cuenta a modificar: 0
Nombre: Cantidad: 0
```

any ideas? This is just part of a very big method but this is the only Scanner that is causing trouble.

Comment: I think this could be due to the fact that you are using nextInt() instead of nextLine() for "cuenta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextInt()` method leaves the `\n` (end line) symbol and is picked up immediately by `nextLine()`, skipping over the next input.  What you want to do is use `nextLine()` for everything, and parse it later:

```
String nextIntString = keyboard.nextLine(); //get the number as a single line
int nextInt = Integer.parseInt(nextIntString); //convert the string to an int
```

This is by far the easiest way to avoid problems--don't mix your "next" methods.  Use only `nextLine()` and then parse `int`s or separate words afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `s.nextLine()` when you want to wait for a user enter key before scanning next input.
Use:

```
try {
    cuenta = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
} catch (Exception e){
    //Do whatever you want.
}
```